# Join strings without repeating delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net

a friend told me about a function to combine strings with a delimiter without having to worry about whether or not the delimiter is already present in the strings, but i cant remember the function

ex:

```
 var stringArray = new string[]{"windows", "\users", "JohnSmith", "\Documents"}; 
 var tempString = whateverFunction(stringArray, "\")
```

joins the strings into

```
tempstring = "windows\users\JohnSmith\Documents"
```

any help with this would be great, thanks

Comment: Is the single backslash before `users` and `Documents` in the resulting `tempstring` intended?

Comment: @PoByBolek yes, that's to illustrate the "without repeating delimiter" part of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Path.Combine()`, though that is specific to paths, and not a general answer to the question.

Comment: @Selman22 yes it does; Path.Combine is a function that combines strings without repeating the delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

You might be thinking of [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx), but it doesn't work quite like you describe.

```
var stringArray = new[] {"windows", "\\users", "JohnSmith", "\\Documents"}; 
var tempString = Path.Combine(stringArray);
```

That results in `\Documents` because it took the last as an absolute path. This method does what you are asking for (trims the joining character from the edges, not throughout).

```
string WhateverFunction(string[] values, char join)
{
    return String.Join(join.ToString(), values.Select(x => x.Trim(join)));
}

var stringArray = new[] {"windows", "\\users", "JohnSmith", "\\Documents"}; 
var tempString = WhateverFunction(stringArray, '\\');
```

Results in `windows\users\JohnSmith\Documents`

Answer (score 0):

I would use explicit string arrays, in which case "\users", etc., is invalid with the back-slash - it requires two back-slashes (to escape the slash).

```
 string[] stringArray = new string[]{"windows", "\\users", "JohnSmith", "\\Documents"}; 

 string tempString = String.Join("\\", stringArray).Replace("\\\\","\\");
 Console.WriteLine(tempString);
 // windows\users\JohnSmith\Documents
```

Replace() is used to remove the duplication of the slashes.

Comment: What's an ambiguous call error?  You do realize the question is about C#, don't you?  A variable declared with var is no more ambiguous than a variable declared with an explicit type.

Comment: You are right, I was using "\" in Join which created the error. I do know it is C#!